# Ajax call work slow.Can make it fast?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm filling "ReportToadd" dropdownlist form "ddlLanguage" dropdownlist when select index change through JavaScript and ajax in asp.net mvc.This work fine but take much time to fill child dropdownlis"ReportToadd".it take 4 to 5 second to fill second dropdownlist.How can make it fast.please help and thanks in advance

JavaScript code:

```
$(function () {
    $('select#ddlLanguage').change(function () {
        var languageId = $(this).val();            
        var projectType ='@(TempData["projectType"])';    
        $.ajax({
            url: "/SEI/Report/FillReport",
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({ languageId: languageId, projectType: projectType }),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#ReportToAdd").html("");
                $.each(data, function (key, result) {
                    $('select#ReportToAdd').append(
                        '<option value="' + result.Value + '">'
                        + result.Text +
                        '</option>');
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and dropdownlist are:

```
        string projectType = "SEI_ADULT";                                              
        @Html.DropDownList("ddlLanguage", SixSeconds.Utils.SelectList<SixSeconds.Models.Language>("Name", ""), new { @id = "ddlLanguage", style = "width:300px;" }) <br /> 
        TempData["projectType"] = projectType;                                                 
        @Html.DropDownList("ReportToAdd", Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), new { @id = "ReportToAdd", style = "width:300px;" })
```

and Json method is like

```
 public JsonResult FillReport(int languageId,string projectType,string selectedValue, bool showCredits = true)
    {
        DataAccessObject<ReportType> dao = new DataAccessObject<ReportType>();
        DataAccessObject<Language> ldao = new DataAccessObject<Language>();
        //IEnumerable<ReportType> list = criteria != null ? dao.Filter(criteria) : dao.All().ToList();
        IEnumerable<ReportType> list = dao.All().ToList();
        IEnumerable<Language> Llist = ldao.All().ToList();

        list = list.Where(a => a.ProjectType.ToString() == projectType).ToList();
        list = list.OrderBy(r => r.CustomOrder);

        List<SelectListItem> result = new List<SelectListItem>();
        result.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "", Text = "" });
        foreach (ReportType t in list)
            {
            foreach (Language l in t.Languages.Where(a=>a.Id==languageId).ToList())
            {               
                    string displayText = t.Name + " (" + l.Name + ")" + (showCredits ? " - " + (t.Code == "BTP" ? 10 : t.Credits) + " " + App_GlobalResources.FieldLabels.Credits : "");
                    string value = t.Id + "-" + l.Id + "-" + (t.Code == "BTP" ? 10 : t.Credits) + "-" + t.Code + "-" + l.Code.Replace("-", "_");
                    result.Add(new SelectListItem() { Selected = (selectedValue == value), Value = value, Text = displayText });
             }
        }
        return Json(result);

    }
```

Comment: There's two things that make a request slow; the server takes a long time to process the request or a lot of data must be transferred. If the former, improve your server-side logic. If the latter, look in to paging or filtering.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan note: it *could* also be the case that the client-side processing in the callback is what is taking the time. But *most likely* it is server-side time and bandwidth due to data size, agreed.

Comment: True - although that's normally a byproduct of a lot of data being returned in the request.

Comment: @RaeMujahidAbbas - How big is your return set?

Comment: First dropdownlist"ddlLanguage" have filled by 20 language and tow things are passed to ajax to fill second dropdownlis"ReportToAdd" one is languageId and second projectType.it take time on javascript function or ajax call.FillReport work fine

Comment: @The Sharp Ninja- child dropdownlist"ReportToAdd" is  filled by 7 record against every language.when language change from first dropdownlist"ddlLanguage"

Comment: Replace `each` loop with `for` loop because it is faster. It will not improve the performance significantly but it would help.

Answer (score 2):

One way of updating your db query is to not use `All` and pass down the `Where`.

Also, `Llist` is never used so you are getting all the Languages from the db for nothing.

try:-

```
//IEnumerable<Language> Llist = ldao.All().ToList();
IEnumerable<ReportType> list = dao.Where(a => a.ProjectType.ToString() == projectType)
                                   .OrderBy(r => r.CustomOrder).ToList();
```

instead of :-

```
IEnumerable<ReportType> list = dao.All().ToList();
IEnumerable<Language> Llist = ldao.All().ToList();

list = list.Where(a => a.ProjectType.ToString() == projectType).ToList();
list = list.OrderBy(r => r.CustomOrder);
```

This will pass the where and order by to the db instead of doing it in code.

Comment: your answer is appreciated but i have to filter list record as
see here:
`if (!currentUser.IsLeadershipBCUser() && currentUser.Account.Role != Role.Master)
            {
                list = list.Where(a => a.Code != "L_BC").ToList();
            }`
so i can't use direct 
`IEnumerable<ReportType> list = dao.Where(a => a.ProjectType.ToString() == projectType)
                                   .OrderBy(r => r.CustomOrder).ToList();`

Comment: Sorry... I cant see any `if` in your method.